# What does it mean if file_get_contents returns "HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403"?

Tags: php, api, github, oauth

This error is seems to come every time

```
 file_get_contents(https://api.github.com/users/AnyUsername/following): failed 
 to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\Github\test.php on line 40
```

Below are some of the lines of code:

```
$data = array(
'client_id' => 'a7f10b4ef02b11843ae7',
'client_secret' => '89b227cbb3705099c7281ba367cfc5f868ea4f4b',
'redirect_uri'=>'http://localhost/Github/test.php',
'code'=>$code,

);

$post=http_build_query($data);
$url="https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?".$post;
$contents=file_get_contents($url);
$explode1 = explode('access_token=', $contents);
$explode2 = explode('&scope=user', $explode1[1]);
$access_token = $explode2[0];
$opts = [ 'http' => [
           'method' => 'GET',
           'header' => [ 'User-Agent: PHP']
                ]
    ];
    //fetching user data
$url = "https://api.github.com/user?access_token=".$access_token;
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$user_data = json_decode($data, true);
$_SESSION['user'] = $user_data['login'];
$_SESSION['email']=$user_data['email'];
$img=$user_data['avatar_url'];
$name=$user_data['name'];

    //fetching user following
$url="https://api.github.com/users/".$_SESSION['user']."/following";
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$user_data = json_decode($data, true);
```

The error is in second last line, this is generally a GitHub API
through PHP.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function getSslPage($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result; } echo getSslPage('https://api.github.com/users/TheYkk/following');
```

> Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header (http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required). Check https://developer.github.com for other possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have permission to access the "following" list for the user specified.

> `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in`

I'm just testing that URL format in my browser now, it seems I'm unable to view the JSON for any user's "following" list besides my own.